# Ruby elegant way of adding all even or odd indexed digits of a number?

Tags: ruby

Is there a method that does not require a .each that can elegantly add all the odd/even indexed digits.

```
eg. 872653627

Odd: 7 + 6 + 3 + 2 = 18
Even: 8 + 2 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28
```

Comment: There will be one if you write it. So why not start with some code?

Comment: Well I was going to use a `.each`,`counter`, `an if statement with a mod` and `two variables for holding even and odd`. A truly shameful piece of code.

Comment: @StevieG and now you're looking for a way to do it without `each`, counters, `if` statements, modulo and variables?

Comment: No, just looking for an elegant and efficient way

Comment: I see you haven't selected an answer. None were helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).             # turn string into individual numbers
  partition.with_index { |_, i| i.odd? }.  # separate the numbers into 2 arrays
  map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }                 # sum each array
#=> [18, 28]
```

Comment: IMHO Elegant means "is readable, understandable and hides well its complexity". This covers all three!

Answer (score 3):

```
num=872653627

num.to_s.split("").
    select.each_with_index { |str, i| i.odd? }.
    map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

and similarly with `i.even?`.

Comment: He asks for no `each`, and I feel like I see an `each` here.

Answer (score 2):

```
number = 872653627

result = number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).group_by.with_index {|_, i| i.odd? }.map {|k,v| [k,v.inject(0, :+)]}.to_h

odd = result[true]
even = result[false]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num=872653627
odd = even = 0
num.to_s.split("").
  each_with_index { |data, index| index.odd? ? odd += data.to_i : even += data.to_i }

odd #=> 18 
even #=> 28
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x, odd, even, alt = 872653627, 0, 0, false
until x.zero?
  x, r = x.divmod(10)
  alt ? odd += r : even += r
  alt ^= true
end

odd #=> 18
even #=> 28
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question!

Anyways, the solution is pretty simple.

```
string = "872653627"
```

For Even Indexed Digits

```
string.chars.select.with_index{|e,i|i.even?}.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

For Odd Indexed Digits

```
string.chars.select.with_index{|e,i|i.odd?}.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the method of each_slice is allowed, transforming the number to array then slice would be concise.

```
num = 872653627.to_s.split(//).map{|x| x.to_i}.reverse
even= num.each_slice(2).inject(0){|total , obj| total + obj[0]}
odd = num.each_slice(2).inject(0){|total , obj| total + obj[1]}
```

I got confused about the definition of the odd/even indexed digits here, please feel free to change the obj[0], obj[1] and .reverse to fit various definitions of odd/even indexed digits.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
num = '872653627'
[/.(\d)/,/(\d).?/].map{|re| num.scan(re)}.map{|x| x.flatten.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)}
#=> [18, 28]
```